# Using nmap with torsocks on VPN

Tags: torsocks

I am trying to use nmap with torsocks while connected to VPN. When i used this (sudo torsocks nmap -sS 1.2.3.4) command i am getting "nmap route_dst_netlink: can't find interface "tun0" torsocks".

And did some research and found -e option. When used this:

sudo torsocks nmap -sS -e tun0 1.2.3.4

I got this (I cannot figure out what source address to use for device tun0, does it even exist? QUITTING!).

I am really confused how to do achieve this job. Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot perform a SYN scan over Tor, so this isn't possible. See also: [Test nmap over tor with psad](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/21010/test-nmap-over-tor-with-psad/21011)